# Paypal new sandbox account no api credentials generated

Tags: paypal, sandbox, credentials

I have created a new Sandbox account in PayPal. This is a merchant account.
I've clicked on the profile button and there I've checked the API Credentials page.
The page is totally empty.

How can I get them?
Should I trigger something else to have them generated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the account is a premier or a business account.  You will not have any if this is for a personal account.  If you have the correct account type, try logging into the actual test account and going to the profile, and then to the API credentials page and manually generate them.  See if this allows you to generate the credentials that you are needing.

Comment: The account I am looking at is a business account. I am at the profile, and on the API credentials page I cannot see anything. You can see it here:http://postimage.org/image/lu68jxym3/ http://postimage.org/image/hx50ig5ex/

Comment: Log into that actual account and try generating the credentials.  From the screenshot, you are only in the developer account.  If you go into the actual business account, and go to the profile you should be able to generate the credentials.

Comment: So I'm logged into the developer account and if I log into the Sanbox test page with the business user, and I click on the My Profile under under My Account, I get the standard sandbox login page: http://postimage.org/image/4omdrbsyx/

Comment: I'd also like to add on that i'm having the exact same problem.  Log on where? If you click "sandbox site" under the business account, it takes you to a sandbox login which then says you must login to use the sandbox but then you can't go any further.

Comment: We are currently working to resolve these issues, of the pages logging you out. The issue is hit or miss, dpending on which box you hit for generating your API Credentials/accounts. You might try creating an account a few times, as you may hit one of the boxes that we have corrected the issue on. Also, as a work around, until we have this issue resolved, you could try using the SDK API credentials that are provided. This would atleast allow you to make API calls, you just wouldn't be able to log into the actual sandbox seller account to veiw any transactions or make any changes.

Comment: PP_MTS_Chad Thanks for the info! Now I was able to generate the credentials!

Comment: PP_MTS_Chad - I don't understand what you mean by 'hitting the right box'?

Comment: I managed to get API credentials however when I now run my test, i just continously get the "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features." after we "checkout with PayPal". Tried logging in via the link it gives "https://developer.paypal.com/" and that ends me up on the developer homepage. This is a little scary that PayPal hasn't got this right in the test site.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad: So I got past the login issue by making sure I was FIRST logged into the developer site, and then create my cart and checkout. Managed to get the login screen for the purchase, but then got an error "This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address."

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad: in addition to the above, I've also gotten "Fatal Failure" and "Sorry — your last action could not be completed" with "NoFlowSessionCookieException: MAYFLY SESSION COOKIE MISSING Backtrace..."

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad: Managed to get passed the cookie issue by logging into the real PayPal site, then the developer site, then process the checkout. But after 2 transactions I know get "Your PayPal session has timed out" every single time.

Comment: There are still a few issues that are being addressed with the sandbox.  What broswer are you using, you might try using Firefox or Chrome if you are using IE.  There seems to be more issues with IE than the other browsers, and you may want to clear your cookies and cache prior to opening up your developer account.

Comment: This is a nightmare. I log in as the seller and click My Account > Profile and it just gives me a loading icon.

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser?  What specific setting or page are you trying to access from within your profile?

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox is the testing environment where you test your transactions

- To Integrate Your PayPal API You need to do following steps Go to
  https://developer.paypal.com Where you will sign up
- after signup a a confirmation email send to you. Verify that Infrmation from your email inbox
- Then Login to https://developer.paypal.com with your new created credentials
- Then Go to "APPLICATION" Menu
  Option. and Click on Add Sandbox account then system will automatically
  add sandbox account init
- Then you will see your email id contains "-facilitator" in sandbox email.

Answer (score -1):

As i could see the developer.paypal.com with the new look which includes 
sandbox account also and the functionality of the sandbox does work well.

but i couldn't figure out the way to paypal trigger the transaction post back to us 
via IPN (Instant Payment Notification).

I've tried setting up IPN Listener URL in the developer.paypal.com > Tools > IPN simulator

but does not seem to work fine for me..

Comment: You could also try creating two test accounts, a test sandbox buyer account and a test sandbox seller account.  Once you have these two accounts set up, go into the seller account and set up IPN within the seller account.  Then once you the account configured for IPN, and you have your IPN script in place, go through and make a payment.  This will trigger an IPN.  By setting it up in the account, you can also see the IPN that is getting sent out and if your server is successfully acknowledging the communication or what error is coming back.